# Time interval over multiple rows

Tags: r, time, intervals, overlap

I'm trying to solve a problem working with time intervals that I gives me headaches since some time.

This an example of drug prescriptions for two IDs.

```
df <- data.frame('ID' = c('1','1','1','1','2','2'), 'start' = c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-09','2010-02-01', '2010-02-10'),
             'end' = c('2010-01-03', '2010-01-22', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-12', '2010-02-10', '2010-02-12'))

  ID      start        end
1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-03
2  1 2010-01-03 2010-01-22
3  1 2010-01-05 2010-01-07
4  1 2010-01-09 2010-01-12
5  2 2010-02-01 2010-02-10
6  2 2010-02-10 2010-02-12
```

The aim is to create a new column indicating continuous drug use. So in this example both IDs have a continuous use (maxmimum gap between end of prescription and start of next prescription = 1 day). The final result should look like this (logical to indicate continuous use):

```
  ID      start        end  continuous
1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-03 FALSE
2  1 2010-01-03 2010-01-22 TRUE
3  1 2010-01-05 2010-01-07 TRUE
4  1 2010-01-09 2010-01-12 TRUE
5  2 2010-02-01 2010-02-10 FALSE
6  2 2010-02-10 2010-02-12 TRUE
```

I tried to solve this with dplyr and lubridate but didn't manage to get the right result for row 4 as it is not continuous for row 3 but for row 2. Here is my code:

```
df$start <- ymd(df$start)
df$end <- ymd(df$end)
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(continuous = if_else(lag(end) - start >= -1, TRUE, FALSE, missing = FALSE))
```

I would really appreciate some help with this! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the dataframe in groups by ID, then check for each row if the start lies between the start and end of another row. (It always lies between the start and end of itself, so therefore, return `TRUE` if `sum(..)>1`)

Data:

```
df <- data.frame('ID' = c('1','1','1','1','2','2'), 'start' = c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-09','2010-02-01', '2010-02-10'),
                 'end' = c('2010-01-03', '2010-01-22', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-12', '2010-02-10', '2010-02-12'),stringsAsFactors = F)
df$start = as.Date(df$start)
df$end = as.Date(df$end)
```

Code:

```
df$continuous = unlist(lapply(split(df,df$ID), function(x) {lapply(1:nrow(x), 
             function(y) { sum(x$start[y]>=x$start & x$start[y] <= x$end + 1) })>1  }))
```

Output:

```
  ID      start        end continuous
1  1 2010-01-01 2010-01-03      FALSE
2  1 2010-01-03 2010-01-22       TRUE
3  1 2010-01-05 2010-01-07       TRUE
4  1 2010-01-09 2010-01-12       TRUE
5  2 2010-02-01 2010-02-10      FALSE
6  2 2010-02-10 2010-02-12       TRUE
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got confused and deleted my answer. Try running your solution on this data frame, `df1 <- rbind(data.frame(ID = 1, start = as.POSIXct(c('2010-02-03', '2010-02-05'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), end =as.POSIXct(c('2010-02-04', '2010-02-06'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), stringsAsFactors = F), df[df$ID == 2,])`, is that the expected result?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot Florian!

Comment: @Sotos, you are right, thanks for the heads up. I forgot to include the 1 day gap, I'll update my answer.